# Concatenate SCSS files based on an index file and traverse all @imports, do not transpile with sass

Tags: webpack, sass, gulp

I want to generate a single SCSS file based on a tree of smaller, modular SCSS files that are imported via a central index file. Each of those modular / partials can also have their own imports. It’s basically the standard SCSS compilation except I don’t want it compiled to CSS; I instead just want all the SCSS to be grouped into one file that can be imported into other projects that also contain SCSS files, and then have that file transpiled with the rest of them.

Have looked at using `concat()` with Gulp, but it doesn’t know what to do with the imports, and instead just adds all the contents of each file into one.

Example:

```
// _colors.scss
$primary: red;

// _buttons.scss
$buttonBg: $primary;

// _extras.scss
.foo {
    color: $primary;
}

// index.scss
@import "colors";
@import "buttons";
@import "extras";

// OUTPUT FILE
// dist.scss
$primary: red;
$buttonBg: $primary;

.foo {
    color: $primary;
}
```

Comment: I don't think, and don't see, any option to "compile" `sscc` files but output a `scss` file.   But you can use the `@import` (or better use the `@use` rule) to import `css` files as well as `scss`.  So these are pre-compiled and you wouldn't have to worry whether your `@use` paths were still valid when you use the file in another project.

Comment: The alternative is to write a function to scan the `@import`'s and concatenate all those files.  Shouldn't be too hard actually - but not nearly as simple as just `@use` the `css` files.

Comment: Thanks @Mark - yeah the CSS option doesn’t work here because part of what I am outputting is just a bunch of SCSS vars  that then need to be used to override a larger project’s default styling, and those vars won’t end up in the CSS. I have played around with the concat approach and detecting imports... works pretty well

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const concat = require("gulp-concat");
const fs = require("fs");
// const path = require("path");           // not used (yet)
const replace = require("gulp-replace");


let arrayOfImports = [];

function getArrayOfImports(master) {

    // how to handle no such file?  what does sass do?
  let fileContents = fs.readFileSync(master, 'utf8');

  let regexp = /^\s*@use ['"](.*?)['"];/gm;     // @use "colors";
  let useArray = fileContents.matchAll(regexp);  // get all @use... matches in the file

  for (let use of useArray) {
    let usePath = `_${ use[1] }.scss`;  // use[1] = colors, change to _colors.scss
    getArrayOfImports(usePath);         // recursive
    arrayOfImports.push(usePath);       // after recursive call so deeper levels are pushed first
  };
};

function concatSources(cb) {

  getArrayOfImports("index.scss");
  arrayOfImports.push("index.scss");

  console.log(arrayOfImports);
  
  return (
    gulp
      .src(arrayOfImports)
      .pipe(concat('dist.scss'))
      .pipe(replace(/^\s*@use (.*?);\s*\n?/gm, ""))     // strip out @use lines
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'))
  );
  cb();
}


exports.default = gulp.series(concatSources);
```

---

I used `@use` instead of `@import` since use of `@import` is now discouraged, see https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import

And if you switch, use `gulp-dart-sass`.  But you could easily change the above code to use `@imports`.

It handles recursive `@use`'s in the correct order and strips them out of the final `dist.scss`.

Now it can only look for `@use ....;` in your files - if you put something that matches `^\s*@use ['"](.*?)['"];` somewhere in the file where it shouldn't be - it will still be captured but that would be your fault I suppose.

---

TODO:  I haven't investigated calls like `@use 'folder/subFolder/colors4'` yet but they should still work (possible adding a `./` to the beginning in the function).